# jquery css change not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im trying to change a class with jquery click event to display one element differently from the others. I've got a function to change a class and a function to check which item was selected and change its css, but its not working at all.

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="ul1" class="main_menu current-s1">
    <li class="s1"><a class="hov" id="start" href="#" title="Start">START<span></span></a></li>
    <li class="s2"><a class="hov" id="go" href="#" title="Go">GO<span></span></a></li>
    </ul>        
</div>
```

Change class **JQUERY** function:

```
$(".hov").click(function(){
    var cls = $(this).parent("li").attr("class");
    var class1 = "current-"+cls;
    var current = $('#ul1').attr('class').split(' ');
    if(class1 != current[1]) {
    $("#ul1").addClass(class1).removeClass(current[1]);
    }
});
```

Check for current element to display it differently **JQUERY** function

```
$(".main_menu").children("li").each(function() {
var current = "main_menu current-" + ($(this).attr("class"));
var parentClass = $(".main_menu").attr("class");
if (parentClass == current) {
    $(this).children("a").addClass("hov_n");
    $(this).children("a").removeClass("hov");
}
});
```

I experimented with some alerts and it seems the class change function is working, but somehow the other function doesn't change display mode to the other button. Any tips would be welcome ! 
**EDIT** **FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/vrt15/4tbbksxL/

Regards

Comment: When is your second function executed?

Comment: can you explain more about your need? probably there must not need to write  this much of code..

Comment: I agree, try to use the .hasClass() function from Jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a simple function you could get the same effect:

```
$("#menu a").click(
    function(){
        var parent = $('#menu')
        $("a", parent).removeClass("hov_n");
        $("a", parent).addClass("hov");

        $(this).removeClass("hov");
        $(this).addClass("hov_n");
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4tbbksxL/4/

Answer (score 0):

Wahou you done something hard, try this

HTML

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul id="ul1" class="main_menu">
    <li class="s1"><a class="hov_n" id="start" href="#" title="Start">START<span></span></a></li>
    <li class="s2"><a class="hov" id="go" href="#" title="Go">GO<span></span></a></li>
    </ul>        
</div>
```

JS

```
function setClick() {

$(".hov").unbind("click");
$(".hov").click(function(){
   $('.hov_n').eq(0).removeClass("hov_n").addClass("hov");
   $(this).addClass("hov_n").removeClass("hov");
   setClick();
});

}

setClick();
```